# What is used as tie-breaker in mountain classification?

Tags: cycling, tie-breaker

If Mikel Landa finished 2nd in the yesterday's (30 May 2015) stage of [Giro d'Italia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Giro_d%27Italia), both him and Giovanni Visconti would have 125 points in mountains classification. The last stage is flat, no points in mountain classification are given. So in this scenario they would finish both with the same number of points.

> - What is used as a secondary criterion if two riders have the same number of points in mountain classification?
> - Are the rules the same for all Grand Tours (all races in UCI World Tour)?

Bonus question: Has it ever happened in some important stage race that the winner of mountain classification has to be decided by some additional criterion, as two (or more) riders were tied on points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most multi-day tours the rules are similar. The winner is determined in the following order:

1. Most points for the mountain classification
2. Most first places at Hors Categorie climbs
3. Most first places at first categorie climbs
4. And so on...
5. If both riders have finished first on the exact same distribution of mountains. That is, there is still no decisive winner. The rider that has best general classification wins the mountain jersey.

See for example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountains_classification_in_the_Tour_de_France) or the [2012 Tour de France rule book](http://www.letour.fr/le-tour/2012/docs/reglement.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The following reference is from "[Tour de France for Dummies](https://books.google.com/books?id=g0-OU0Q5lk0C&pg=PA37)".  However, it is applicable for all the Grand Tours and the large majority of other major tours.

> If there's a points tie in the final climbing classification, the cyclist with the most first-place finishes in Beyond Category climbs wins.  If there is still a tie, victory is awarded to the rider with the most first-place finishes in Category 1 climbs.  The same process is used, if necessary, in Categories 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

I will add quote from [UCI cycling regulation](http://www.uci.ch/inside-uci/rules-and-regulations/regulations/) - Part II: Road Races (version on 05.02.2015), which seems to confirm what was written in the other answers:

> **2.6.017** 
>   In the event of a tie in the general individual classification by points, the following criteria shall be applied in order until the riders are separated:
>
> 1. number of stage wins;
> 2. number of wins in intermediate sprints counting for the general classification on points;
> 3. general individual classification by time.
>
> In the event of a tie in the general individual mountains classification, the following criteria shall be applied in order until the riders are separated:
>
> 1. number of first places in the highest category climbs;
> 2. number of first places on climbs in the next inferior category and so on;
> 3. general individual classification by time
>
> *(text modified on 1.01.02; 1.01.03; 1.01.05).*